# Colorful idiom/phrase equivalent to French "s'en fourrer jusque là/plein la panse"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, slang, idiom-requests, offensive-language

Is there an expression/idiom in English that comes anywhere close in flavor to the colorful French expression,

> ***s'en mettre*** (or ***fourrer*** or ***foutre***) ***jusque là***
>
> ***s'en mettre*** (or ***fourrer*** or ***foutre***) ***plein la panse*** (or ***plein la lampe***, or ***plein le gosier***)
>
> ***[manger/bouffer] à s'en faire péter/éclater la panse*** (or ***le gosier***, or la ***sous-ventrière***)

Literally, it means something along the lines of, *to stuff oneself up to here [with foods]*/*to stuff/fill one's stomach* (or *throat*) *[with foods] until it bursts*.

It is something that someone might say when, for example, they are invited to a wedding feast, and they are enjoying greatly the idea of being up to a great meal with foods and wine galore.

> *On va s'en mettre plein la panse*/*On va s'en fourrer* (or *mettre*) *jusque là !*
>
> *We're up to a helluva big time with loads of [good] foods and wine!*

Or, after enjoying the feast:

> *On s'en est mis plein la lampe*/*On s'en est mis* (or *fourré*) *jusque lá !*
>
> *We literally stuffed our face and had a helluva good time!*

It is usually associated with wining and dining, though ***s'en fourrer/foutre/mettre jusque là*** can also take a **sexual connotation**, and be used occasionally for other forms of revelry, like monkey business, [***par exemple***](http://www.ibtimes.com/dominique-strauss-kahn-former-imf-head-goes-trial-pimping-1802420).

And so, is there a phrase or idiom in English that might encapsulate **both those connotations** of French ***s'en mettre/fourrer/foutre jusque là***?

> S'EN FOURRER JUSQUE LA
>
> (*Argot*, *vulgaire*) Prendre, avec avidité et excès, de la nourriture, du plaisir, etc.
>
> (*Slang*, *vulgar*) To overindulge oneself, often greedily, in food, drink, or [**other physical desires**](http://www.quoidenews.fr/2015/06/01/dsk-braguette/) (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [Wiktionary](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_fourrer_jusque-l%C3%A0)

Comment: [Mr. Creosote](https://youtu.be/aczPDGC3f8U).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about "**stuffed to the gills**", which usually refers to overeating but can refer to other ways of being full.

Obviously humans don't have gills - i suppose this originated from stuffed fish?

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stuffed+to+the+gills

Comment: As mentioned below, be aware of the **utterly different** but **coincidentally similar sounding** "to the gunnels".  "gills" (on a human) just means "the area around your neck".  So, "stuffed to the gills" simply means "I'm stuffed right up to my neck!!"  **Unrelated**, gunnels is a **nautical term** - in short if a craft is so heavily loaded that it sitting is so low in the water, that water is lapping in, you yell out something like "we're up to the gunnels!"

Comment: (Cont ... ) This is (or was) common-speak on British fishing craft - they go out empty (sitting high in the water) and (if they are making money from a big catch) they come back "stuffed to the gunnels!"  {Note that, it could be interpreted as meaning the caught fish are loaded up to the gunnels-line in the hold (which would, indeed, be heavy enough to make the craft ride very low] or that (for whatever reason) the water level has "reached" ("is up to" - although "down" could be more sensible) the gunnels.) In any event, if a fishing craft is stuffed, it is "stuffed to the gunnels!" }

Comment: Max regarding your comment "i suppose this originated from stuffed fish" ... hmm, I don't see that.  It's normal (if old-fashioned) to use the word "gills" in connection with humans, simply to mean "around your neck". You might say something like, oh, he's tender around the gills, he got whacked on the gills, that necklace looks awfully pretty on your gills, etc. stuff to the gills just seems part of that?

Comment: @JoeBlow you may be right.

Comment: *Re:* **gills** "a little pale around the gills" is in English and American collections on-line. Possibly queasy or hung-over or unwell, but not necessarily from overeating

Answer (score 10):

A colourful expression may be:

to ***[pig out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pig+out)***:

> - to eat a lot -  *Our kids dream of staying up late and pigging out on junk food.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

also:

***[Eat (one's) fill](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eat+fill)***  is an idiomatic expression close to the one you are suggesting:

> - to eat as much as one can hold; to eat as much as one wants. Please eat your fill. There's plenty for everyone.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

and:

***[eat heartily](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+eat+heartily)***:

> - to eat freely and with relish.

(Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary)

Answer (score 6):

***[To gorge oneself](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gorge)*** has this meaning:

> Eat a large amount greedily; fill oneself with food

Since the word *gorge* has the archaic meaning of *throat* (see the same link referenced above) it is likely a fairly good equivalent of the French phrase, which admittedly is more colourful, to say the least.

Answer (score 5):

Josh beat me to "eat one's fill" so I'll present an alternative for after eating:

We would say that we were [***full to bursting***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-full-to-bursting).

> to be very full
>
> *Collins English Dictionary*

--

> ***I've eaten so much I'm full to bursting!***

Answer (score 4):

It depends how colloquial you want to be.

***Full to the gunwales (gunnels)*** is a nautical metaphor relating to a ship which is so laden the water comes up to the tops of its sides. (*Gunwales* is from *gun walls* - 15th century)

That is the one I would probably use and, since it is self-deprecatory (comparing oneself to a heavy old ship) would be acceptable in most places in Britain.

My problem, as a callow youth, was in how to say something similar in French. To everyone's amusement round a Marseilles dinner table I ventured *je suis plein* (I am pregnant - but not human pregnant, animal pregnant).

Comment: Also:  "...packed to the gills," (in keeping with the nautical theme).

Comment: Certainly, anyone from a British (north or south) coastal fishing family would indeed say "to the gunnels" (", laddie").

Comment: I've always wondered if there was any connection between "to the gills" and "to the gunnels" - other than just general confusion between the two.

Comment: Thank God there are still a few people alive old enough to know these terms  :/

Comment: @JoeBlow "still few people alive...." Tsk! Poor WS2, you make it sound as if he's ready for the bucket. Long life to WS2

Answer (score 3):

To **eat someone out of house and home** (idiom, humorous):

to eat a lot of someone else's food

> *'he would eat them out of house and home if he continued to run through biscuits at his present rate'*

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eat-someone-out-of-house-and-home)

The phrase was first printed in c1598, in [William Shakespeare: Henry IV Pt 2, Act II Scene I](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=henry4p2&Act=2&Scene=1&Scope=scene):

> Mistress Quickly: *'It is more than for some my lord; it is for all, all I have. He hath eaten me out of house and home; he hath put all my substance into that fat belly of his: but I will have some of it out again, or I will ride thee o'nights like the mare.'*

Answer (score 2):

I believe "pigged out" might be the phrase you are looking for. [Here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pig+out) is a definition. The idea is that one has eaten largely and ravenously. That one has made a pig of oneself.

Alternatively, "bung full" or "filled to the bung" have a coarse sound but are more commonly used by the British than Americans.

Comment: I'm British, and I've never heard either of "bung full" or "filled to the bung". Sometimes if someone has a very bad cold, we will say *he/she is all bunged up".

Comment: It was an expression my mother used. Perhaps it is more local than I thought. She was Scottish

Answer (score 2):

I think ***pork away*** could make an acceptable candidate for my own question. Not sure, though, if it is a common expression or not...

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22porking+away%22&biw=343&bih=225&prmd=vin&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4tKCHz9nLAhUHHxoKHdKgD8wQ_AUICygG)
>
> *Although Obama has observed no "appetite" in Congress to address the pressing illegal immigrant issue this year, there was some good news at the picnic. The president noted that the members of Congress and their families were **porking away** so much of the free food that there would not be a lot of leftovers.*
>
> [LA Times](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/washington/2010/06/obama-oil-spill-congress-picnic.html)
>
> *I was wrong. I'm sorry I was jealous. Just go ahead. Pork away pal. F..k her blue.*
>
> [Stylistics: Prospect & Retrospect](https://books.google.fr/books?id=z5daQmIFrgEC&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=%22pork+away+pal%22&source=bl&ots=6aXWr6prHI&sig=TuQEKLo6ZZQSvu7B7svK-jH2L7s&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv3vPL09nLAhVDcBoKHa7VBoAQ6AEILTAI#v=onepage&q=%22pork%20away%20pal%22&f=false)
>
> **pork out**
>
> *informal* Stuff oneself with food; overeat:
>   *I porked out on the roast pig*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/pork)

Comment: I think there may be a play on words here! [Pack away](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pack-away), means to eat a lot of food.

Comment: 1. _Porking_ in the first example refers to "pork barrel" - metaphor for  appropriation of government spending for localized projects 2. In the second _Pork_ is the same as "F..k" that is actually reiterated _"Pork away pal. F..k her blue"_

Comment: +1, while "pork" for "engage in sexual activity" and "pork out" for "stuff oneself with food" are separate phrases, and AFAICT the use of "pork away" in the LA Times quote you give is an unusual use of the phrase, the chances are in any situation where the double meaning is relevant, you should be able to do *something* with these similar phrases that captures the essence of what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

When one has had (more than) their fill of food, a common exclamation - accompanied by a salute, of sorts, in which the hand slightly lifts the chin - is: **"I'm up to *here*".**

This saying is also used to indicate a "bellyful" of aggravation, advice, chores, etc. The same gesture goes with the negative statement: **"I've had it up to *here* ."**

Comment: @cobaltduck - You're right - I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to not restrict the idiom to food, but rather allow for the other physical appetites, one option is:

> Fill one's boots

This may be a bit *too* idiomatic as I'm not sure I've ever heard it used outside of the UK, but it basically conveys the meaning of having (or taking) as much of something as one can, be it food, sexual pleasure, money - whatever is on offer. Usually, though, it's food, drink or sex (though that may just be south-eastern England).

Dictionary definition:

> informal Have as much of something as one wants; do something to the full:
>   *'fill your boots with spicy Szechuan food for under five bucks a plate'*

From Oxford Dictionaries, [here.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fill-one's-boots)